# Matching polynomial, but $K_2$ is replaced by $K_3$. Have these been studied?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, polynomials

Given a simple graph $G=(V,E)$, we can consider matchings, $M\subseteq E$,
where $M$ is a *matching* iff no vertex is shared between different edges.
The number of edges in $M$ is denoted $|M|$.

The [matchings-generating polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatchingPolynomial.html) of $G$ is defined as

$$ p_G(x) = \sum_{M  \in \text{matchings of } G} x^{|M|}. $$
Classically, the Touchard polynomials (coeffs given by Stirling numbers of the second kind) are obtained by choosing $G$ to be a certain bipartite graph on $2n$ edges (see Lemma 5.1, C.D. Godsil. *Algebraic combinatorics*.)

Now, an edge is a complete graph on $2$ vertices, so
let instead look for triangles in a graph $G$. A *triangle* is just a subset $\{a,b,c\} \subseteq V$ where $ab,ac,bc$ are edges in $G$.
Define analogously a $3$-matching $T$ as a subset of triangles of $G$,
where no two triangles share a vertex.
The number of triangles in a $3$-matching is denoted $|T|$.

Let us define the "*3-matchings-generating polynomial*" of $G$ as
$$ q_G(x) = \sum_{T  \in \text{3-matchings of } G} x^{|T|}. $$

Note that this is not the same as the [clique polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CliquePolynomial.html)
or the [vertex cover polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VertexCoverPolynomial.html), or the [independence polynomial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndependencePolynomial.html),
but maybe $q_G(x)$ is one of these polynomials for some different graph $G'$?

Have these 3-matching polynomials (or the more general "$k$-matching polynomials", by non-intersecting $m$-tuples of $k$-cliques) been studied somewhere?

Comment: One big difference between 2-matchings and 3-matchings is that the problem of deciding whether a graph has a complete 3-matching is NP-complete. See http://profs.sci.univr.it/~rrizzi/classes/Complexity/provette/Mirko/pt_fine.pdf. This suggests that $q_G(x)$ will not be as nice as $p_G(x)$.

Comment: @RichardStanley That is a nice comment! I did compute the above polynomial for the complete graph, and some families of m-partite graphs, and got some OEIS hits, but the 3-partite interpretation was not there. 
I am then more confident this might be a good area for a student of mine to do some exploration (and more importantly, prove the OEIS connections).

Comment: Instead of counting 3 matchings, it is more natural to look at $<=3$ matchings. One variable case is somewhat degenerate. If you look at the multi-variable matching polynomial, each term  form a spanning forests consisting of mutually non adjacent edges and vertices (these are called dimers-monomers by Heilmann and Lieb). So we want a polynomial where each term consisting of disjoint triangles ,edges and vertices but it will be hard to make it agree with the characteristic polynomial when the graph is a tree.

Comment: @CHUAKS I think that this model also can be made into the (perhaps multivariate) independence polynomial of some associated graph.

Comment: @CHUAKS, but  $q_G(x)$ is not always gonna be real-rooted; one needs some conditions on $G$, (mathing polynomials are always real-rooted though). See my answer for when triangles does not give something real-rooted....

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Let $G' = (V',E')$ be the graph where $V$  consists of all triangles in $G$. Two vertices (triangles) are connected by an edge if they share a vertex.
With this, $q_G(x)$ is exactly the independence polynomial of the graph $G'$.

Edit: Looking at small graph triangulations, one can easily be tricked to believe that the  $q_G(x)$ are always real-rooted. However, there is a graph on 9 vertices, (a triangle $T$, and then 3 triangles attached to the three vertices of $T$).
This makes $G'$ into a claw and  $q_G(x)$ has two complex roots, (indep. polys of claw-free graphs are known to real-rooted, so the above construction is in some sense the smallest counterexample; hard to find by just randomly sampling small graphs!).